# Reading files one by one and resolve them

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have multiple(hundreds) of files in a folder i need to read. Currently I am using a method that reads all the files and then returns the content as an array. But i need to change it so that i read a file and i send it to the client and then i read the second one and so one until the end... to make it more efficient. Any suggestions?

Currently code:

```
const fse = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");
return (
  fse
    .readdir(direc)
    .then((filenames: any) => {
      return filenames.map((filename: any) => path.join(direc, filename));
    })
    .then((filepaths: any) => {
      return filepaths.map((filepath: any) =>
        fse.readFile(filepath).then((filecontents: any) => {
          return JSON.parse(filecontents);
        })
      );
    })
    // Promise.all consumes an array of promises, and returns a
    // new promise that will resolve to an array of concrete "answers"
    .then((filecontents: any) => Promise.all(filecontents))
    .then((realcontents: any) => {
      return realcontents;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting all the file reading promises in an array and then calling Promise.all, chain them together. I'm not very familiar with Typescript syntax, so I'll provide an example code in plain JS and I hope you can convert whatever's needed:

```
// ...
.then(filepaths => {
  let promise = Promise.resolve();
  filepaths.forEach(filepath => {
      promise = promise
                .then(() => fs.readFile(filePath))
                .then(handleFile)
                .catch(handleError);
  });
  return promise;
})
// ...
```

Then you just need to create a `handleFile` function that takes in the file contents of a single file and does whatever you want with it (parses it, sends data back over a response, etc.). This way each file will be handled in order. You're going to want your `handleError` function to return a resolved promise, too, so one failed file read doesn't break the entire chain.

Comment: can you add the JS code for handleFile and handleError if possible?

Comment: Because I am confused how to get the file content and how be control that the chain wont break

Comment: Its not quite working because it doesnt return all the files it returns only the first one

Comment: I have no idea what server framework you're using, so I can't tell you how that would work. Just make sure that whatever functions you're using to send data back to the client, you're not using one that closes the connection after sending, or else you won't be able to send the next file over.

Comment: Punk this is the handlefile i created or should it be different?
async handleFile(filecontents:any)
    {
        return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(filecontents));
    }

Comment: That'll just parse it and then pass it on to the next `.then` in the chain, which in this case won't do anything. The only time that value will be used is the last file, where there's nothing chained after it except your actual data handling. Your `handleFile` function should parse, process, and SEND the data. (You also don't need to explicitly call `Promise.resolve` in a `.then` handler, as Promises will automatically wrap returned values in a resolved Promise, so you can just return data directly.)